Store generic closure in swift
I have the following struct which I can't touch:
struct MyFeature<Value> {
    let id: UUID
    let startDate: Date
    let expirationDate: Date
    let value: Value?

    typealias Transform<RawJsonType> = ((RawJsonType) -> Value?)

    init?<RawJsonType>(json: [String: Any],
                       startDate: Date,
                       expirationDate: Date,
                       transform: Transform<RawJsonType>) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.startDate = startDate
        self.expirationDate = expirationDate
        self.value = Self.parseValue(json: json, transform: transform)
    }

    private static func parseValue<RawJsonType>(json: [String: Any], transform: Transform<RawJsonType>) -> Value? {
        // Oversimplified logic
        guard let someJson = json as? RawJsonType else {
            return nil
        }
        return transform(someJson)
    }
}

I want to "store" the transform closure to be used at a later time.  I want to store it in memory, but some times it would also be nice to have a static variable (as shown below) that I could use to instantiate this Feature of a given Value type.
This is what I was trying to do:
struct MyFeatureMetadata<Value> {
    typealias Transform<RawJsonType> = ((RawJsonType) -> Value?)
    let name: String
    let id: UUID
    let startDate: Date
    let endDate: Date
    let transform: Transform<Any> // !

    init<RawJsonType> (
        name: String,
        id: UUID = UUID(),
        startDate: Date = .distantPast,
        endDate: Date = .distantFuture,
        transform: @escaping Transform<RawJsonType>
    ) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.startDate = startDate
        self.endDate = endDate
        self.transform = transform // ! Cannot assign value of type...
    }
}

Obviously I can't just "store" the closure.
This is how I want to use it:
enum SomeFeature: String {
    case basic
    case expert
}

extension MyFeatureMetadata<SomeFeature> {
    static var someFeature = Self(name: "some") { (rawJson: String) in
        SomeFeature(rawValue: rawJson) ?? .expert
    }
}

// At some random point I want to be able to instantiate my Feature:
let myFeature: MyFeature<SomeFeature> = MyFeature(
    json: ["": ""], // Someone else is going to provide the json
    startDate: MyFeatureMetadata.someFeature.startDate,
    expirationDate: MyFeatureMetadata.someFeature.endDate,
    transform: MyFeature.someFeature.transform
)

the value of my feature will only be available if the provided json had the enough data to crate the feature...
Anyways, everything screams type erasure to me, but I can't figure out how to do it or if I'm taking the right approach.
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

You are aware of the flaw in the design of struct MyFeature? Putting this aside, it should be possible to have several free functions (possibly embedded in a namespace (aka a Swift enum), whose signature is (Input) -> Output? which you could pass in as an argument to a generic member function of struct MyFeature where the type of the struct (Value) matches Output and the type of the generic member function, say T, matches Input. Done.

Instead of passing generic type RawJsonType to init of MyFeatureMetadata, you should make it a generic type of MyFeatureMetadata. Here is my suggestion fix for your current code:
struct MyFeatureMetadata<Value, RawJsonType> {
    typealias Transform = ((RawJsonType) -> Value?)
    let name: String
    let id: UUID
    let startDate: Date
    let endDate: Date
    let transform: Transform

    init(
        name: String,
        id: UUID = UUID(),
        startDate: Date = .distantPast,
        endDate: Date = .distantFuture,
        transform: @escaping Transform
    ) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.startDate = startDate
        self.endDate = endDate
        self.transform = transform
    }
}

enum SomeFeature: String {
    case basic
    case expert
}

extension MyFeatureMetadata where Value == SomeFeature, RawJsonType == String {
    static var someFeature = Self(name: "some") { rawJson in
        SomeFeature(rawValue: rawJson) ?? .expert
    }
}

